# What is the adjective of "Technology" for the noun "Age"

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct :

- This is a technology age.
- This is a technological age.

I've heard of "the age of technology", but I'm not sure about the first choice. Also, I feel when I use "technological", the noun should be a method or a mean.

Answer (score 1):

"**technological**" means "*relating to or using technology*". So if this is what you meant then this adjective is the right one. There's also "**technologic**" *(archaic version of **technological**)* but it's most probably out of use in PDE.

"**technology**" can appear as part of a compound noun meaning "*associated with technology or relating to it*"

Comment: Agreed about technologic: I have never heard it used.

Comment: So, which one is appropriate in the case of "age"?

Comment: I hoped logic would work.. well, "**technological age**" means "*an age relating to technology*".